# I am having trouble with this query (only iPad). It is not being picked up while iPhone landscape and portrait work fine

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having trouble with this query (only iPad). It is not being picked up while iPhone landscape and portrait work fine

```
/*iPhone 6 Portrait*/
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width:
 667px) and (orientation :     portrait) {
body {
      background: red;
     }
  }

/*iPhone 6 landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width:
 667px) and (orientation :    landscape) {
body {
 background: green;
    }
}

/* iPad Air */
 @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and  
(orientation : landscape) { 
 body {
 background: yellow;
  }
```

for my [web](http://www.meghashare.ml/)